# PHP UTF8 Database

Tags: php, database, encoding, mysqli

I have a database which is encoded in UTF8_bin.
Whenever I try to echo something on that database I get questionmarks instead of letters. Anyone knows a solution for that? I think it is important to mention that if I do echo to a word in UTF8 it is just fine. The problem is getting the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have followed these steps.

```
 -> db collation must  be utf8_general_ci
 -> then collation of the table with language has to be utf8_general_ci
 -> in your php connection script put header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
 -> in xhtml head tag put <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 -> after selecting the db in the connection script put mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

     Then check the connection like this,

   if(!mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8')) {
     echo 'the connection is not in utf8';
     exit();
           }
```